# Converting String[] to String[][] in java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

how do i convert this :

```
String[] {"4444 QH", "5656 JR", "8976 RR"}
```

into this:

```
new string[][] {"4444", "5656", "8976"} {"QH", "JR", "RR"}
```

That possible?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I want to get record number with clausa WHERE 'noregis'=4444 and 'area' = QH from the table. as like there 13 columns i try to store in jtable. These String [] pass by another jinternal frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the String array and fetch each string which has two parts. You can split this at the whitespace and get the two parts you need.

If you want to have a different format in the final matrix you can change the for loop accordingly. Overall it would look sth like this I guess:

```
String[] arrayA= {"4444 QH", "5656 JR", "8976 RR"};
String [][] matrix = new String [2][arrayA.length];

String splitted [];
int i=0;

for (String s : arrayA){
    splitted=s.split(" ");
    matrix[0][i]=splitted[0];
    matrix[1][i]=splitted[1];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @nkal, its work in my scenario, for further stream i use your code combining StringBuilder with, then i be able to put in query WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the first array and then split each string in two words to populate the new 2D Array.